# After change the query also showing the same data in crystal report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I am showing the data according to the query in crystal report in c#.net desktop application. Problem causing is that when I am change the query, query is changing and according to that query in temp table showing the data also, but in crystal report it is not showing the new data it is showing the same data which is previous after the query change also.

For ex : I want to print bill no 1 so that time okay. But when I want to print bill no 2 at that time also in crystal report showing bill no 1 only. So, that's why I unable to print the bill no 2.

Here is my code in the button click event

```
private void btn_previewdocument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string mtmptbl = "TmpRetailInvoicePrint";
            RetailInvoicePrint frm = new RetailInvoicePrint();
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            timer1.Enabled = true;

            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cn.ConnectionString);
            ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

            string qryPreviewDocument = " SELECT Client.clientname as ClientName, " + System.Environment.NewLine;
            qryPreviewDocument += " RetailInvoice.invoiceno as InvoiceNo, " + System.Environment.NewLine;
            qryPreviewDocument += " RetailInvoice.pono as PoNO, RetailInvoice.issuedate as IssueDate, RetailInvoice.duedate as DueDate, " + System.Environment.NewLine;
            qryPreviewDocument += " RetailInvoice.discount as Discount, RetailInvoice.shipping as Shipping, RetailInvoice.tax as Tax, RetailInvoice.vat as Vat, " + System.Environment.NewLine;
            qryPreviewDocument += " RetailInvoice.sese as Sese, RetailInvoice.paymenttype as PaymentType, RetailInvoice.chequeno as Chequeno, RetailInvoice.totalamt as TotalAmt, " + System.Environment.NewLine;
            qryPreviewDocument += " RetailInvoice.description as Description, RetailInvoice.paymentpaid as PaymentPaid, RetailInvoice.subtotal as Subtotal, " + System.Environment.NewLine;

            qryPreviewDocument += " RetailInvoicePayment.productid as ProductName, RetailInvoicePayment.uom as Uom, " + System.Environment.NewLine;
            qryPreviewDocument += " RetailInvoicePayment.quantity as Quantity, RetailInvoicePayment.price as Price" + System.Environment.NewLine;

            qryPreviewDocument += " into " + mtmptbl + " " + System.Environment.NewLine;

            qryPreviewDocument += " from tbl_retailinvoice RetailInvoice LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_retailinvoicepayment RetailInvoicePayment " + System.Environment.NewLine;
            qryPreviewDocument += " ON RetailInvoice.invoiceno = RetailInvoicePayment.invoiceno " + System.Environment.NewLine;
            qryPreviewDocument += " LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_clientdetail Client ON RetailInvoice.clientid = Client.clientid " + System.Environment.NewLine;

            qryPreviewDocument += " where RetailInvoice.BranchID = " + lbl_branchid.Text + " " + System.Environment.NewLine;
            qryPreviewDocument += " and RetailInvoice.YearID = " + lbl_yearid.Text + " " + System.Environment.NewLine;
            qryPreviewDocument += " and RetailInvoice.invoiceno = " + txt_invoice.Text + "";


            string SQL = "select upper(name) as TABLE_NAME FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' and name = '" + mtmptbl + "' order by name";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, cn);
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string qrydrop = "drop table " + mtmptbl + "";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qrydrop, cn);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }

            MyCommand = new SqlCommand(qryPreviewDocument, cn);
            MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cn.Open();
            MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();

            string crReportPath = Application.StartupPath.Replace("bin\\Debug", "") + "\\Print";

            cryRpt.Load(crReportPath + "\\RptRetailInvoice.rpt");

            builder.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["con"];
            string dbName = builder.InitialCatalog;
            string dbDataSource = builder.DataSource;
            string userID = builder.UserID;
            string pass = builder.Password;

            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = dbDataSource;
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = dbName;
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = userID;
            crConnectionInfo.Password = pass;

            Tables Crtables;
            Crtables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;

            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in Crtables)
            {
                crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
            }

            frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            frm.crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();

            Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            frm.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}
```

So, when any one click the "Preview Document" button at that time "btn_previewdocument_Click" event occur.

And I want to do that in this event according to the query data want to display in crystal report.

Advance in thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Before `frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;` add `cryRpt.Refresh();`